# GGR: Users file "/etc/grid-router/users.htpasswd" does not exist

Tags: selenoid

[path picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEEcn.png)

I'd like to know a reason of the following error on Mac:

Docker ggr logs:

```
2022/11/01 00:02:12 [-] [-] [INIT] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [Users file is "/etc/grid-router/users.htpasswd"]
2022/11/01 00:02:12 [-] [-] [INIT] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [Users file "/etc/grid-router/users.htpasswd" does not exist or is a directory]
```

Sequence of commands on Mac:

```
1. cd /etc/grid-router/quota
2. htpasswd -bc users.htpasswd test test-password
3. cat users.htpasswd
test:$apr1$KmVucZGe$S4MXZhc0DHC4J/6i5KW9h/
4. $ pwd
/etc/grid-router/quota
5. test.xml file was created appropriately in quota directory
6. execute this command from quota directory:
docker run -d --name ggr -p 0.0.0.0:4445:4444 -v /etc/grid-router/:/etc/grid-router:ro --net host aerokube/ggr:latest-release
```

Docker ggr logs:

```
2022/11/01 00:02:12 [-] [-] [INIT] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [Users file is "/etc/grid-router/users.htpasswd"]
2022/11/01 00:02:12 [-] [-] [INIT] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [-] [Users file "/etc/grid-router/users.htpasswd" does not exist or is a directory]
```

Path to the file users.htpasswd on Mac:
please see a pic in the attachment

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File with users list should be in `/etc/grid-router/users.htpasswd`. On your screenshot it is in `/etc/grid-router/quota/users.htpasswd`. That's obviously an error.

Comment: hehe, I wasn't paying attention, thanks Vania, now it's working as expected